# How to know http status codes return by proxy or destination server

Tags: http, proxy, server, http-status-codes

I have a server A connect to server B through by proxy (because server B block my IP) but some time it return HTTP status code > 400, I don't know that is server B's HTTP status code or proxy's HTTP status code.
Sorry my english is not good.